# how to access 404 page with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Here is my folder directory

```
wordpress
  project
    html
      index.html   (html page)
  wp-admin
  wp-content
  wp-includes
  etc...
```

What I want if someone want to access the main directory folder i.e. project folder for example ( domain.com/project ) it redirect to wordress 404.php .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the server finds your 404 page, add the following line to your .htaccess file:

Deny from all
ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.html

Check the docs on Codex: [Creating an Error 404 Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page)

Maybe help plugin: 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-files/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an .htaccess file in the directory you want to restrict. Then you will deny access to your directory and redirect redirect all "403 forbidden" request to a 404 page adding this lines to the .htaccess file:

```
Deny from all
ErrorDocument 403 /404
```

This are the only lines you need to include in this file.

Comment: your code works and not as I aspected means I am not able to access html files inside the project -> html folder

Comment: Do you want only to deny access to certain types of files? php, js, css? As you described in your question, you want to block access to the whole directory. Please elaborate more so I can help you with this.